# Server migration: apache virtual host

Tags: apache2, migration

What is the best and fastest way to replicate apache virtual hosts to a new server?

When I need to change server I recreate all domains one by one with a procedure similar to this one:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/html/sito.com
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/html/sito.com
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/sito.com

sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/sito.com.conf

------
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin mail@mymail.com

    ServerName sito.com
    ServerAlias www.sito.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/sito.com

        <Directory /var/www/html/sito.com>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                # New directive needed in Apache 2.4.3:
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
-------

sudo a2ensite sito.com.conf
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

and with 50, 100 domains this procedure is slow and tedious ...

Is there a fast and secure way to replicate the virtual hosts of the old server to a new server? Can there be problems with permissions and file owners?

I have ssh access and server root, ubuntu 20.04 server, apache, php8.1

Comment: I would copy the contents of directories `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` and `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` from old server to the new one - why recreating them manually? I would also copy the entire `/var/www/html/` but I guess that's what you are doing already? You can use for example `rsync` for that to preserve permissions.

Comment: So long as you're following standard Apache configuration practices, the `/sites-enabled` directory will contain symlinks of files in `/sites-available`, so you will only need to copy the files from `/sites-available`. Once on the new server, use `a2ensite {filename}` to enable the configuration file, which does the symlink creation on its own. Don't forget to restart/reload Apache afterwards 

Comment: I've always been worried about creating problems with file permissions... isn't that a problem? Then in my virtulahost files there is some code added by certbot (redirect to https), but in order to request a new certificate from certbot (with the new server ip) the domain must be enabled and working... will it be a mess if i just copy?